# IntelliJ fails to open FTP conection

Tags: intellij-idea, ftp

I configured `FTP` on one of the servers and it is up and running.
I am able to open it using `Windows Explorer`:

[image: FTP]

But when I try to test connection in `IntelliJ`, I get:

[image: IntelliJ]

Has anyone had this happen?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

FTP log file:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2015-06-03 13:08:54
#Fields: time c-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem sc-status sc-win32-status 

13:41:07 192.168.4.78 [8]USER FIRESTORM\Highlander 331 0
13:41:07 192.168.4.78 [8]PASS - 230 0
13:41:19 192.168.4.78 [5]closed - 421 121
13:44:11 192.168.4.78 [9]USER FIRESTORM\Highlander 331 0
13:44:11 192.168.4.78 [9]PASS - 230 0
13:44:41 192.168.4.78 [10]USER FIRESTORM\Highlander 331 0
13:44:41 192.168.4.78 [10]PASS - 230 0
13:45:28 192.168.4.78 [11]USER FIRESTORM\Highlander 331 0
13:45:28 192.168.4.78 [11]PASS - 230 0
13:45:28 192.168.4.78 [11]CWD / 250 0
13:45:58 192.168.4.78 [12]USER FIRESTORM\Highlander 331 0
13:45:58 192.168.4.78 [12]PASS - 230 0
13:45:58 192.168.4.78 [12]CWD / 250 0
13:46:40 192.168.4.78 [13]USER anonymous 331 0
13:46:40 192.168.4.78 [13]PASS user@example.com 230 0
13:47:10 192.168.4.78 [14]USER anonymous 331 0
13:47:10 192.168.4.78 [14]PASS user@example.com 230 0
13:48:29 192.168.4.78 [15]USER anonymous 331 0
13:48:29 192.168.4.78 [15]PASS user@example.com 230 0
13:48:59 192.168.4.78 [16]USER anonymous 331 0
13:48:59 192.168.4.78 [16]PASS user@example.com 230 0
```

And here is relevant info from idea.log:

```
2015-06-03 10:08:13,824 [2600258]   WARN - i.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode - Could not list the contents of folder "ftp://198.135.4.141/". 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not list the contents of folder "ftp://198.135.4.141/".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:926)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.getChildren(FtpFileObject.java:455)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChild(AbstractFileObject.java:1006)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool.createConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionManager.openConnection(RemoteConnectionManager.java:103)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeContext.getConnection(ServerTreeContext.java:88)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.computeFile(ServerTreeNode.java:269)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.getChildren(ServerTreeNode.java:135)
    at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.SimpleTreeStructure.getChildElements(SimpleTreeStructure.java:25)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$32.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:1624)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1830)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.getChildrenFor(AbstractTreeUi.java:1621)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$4700(AbstractTreeUi.java:62)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$47.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:2708)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1830)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$2500(AbstractTreeUi.java:62)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$58$1.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:3386)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.WebServerTreeBuilder.runBackgroundLoading(WebServerTreeBuilder.java:90)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$58.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:3377)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1830)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$2500(AbstractTreeUi.java:62)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$59.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:3442)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:729)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:657)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3097)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3072)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2731)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2778)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpJBHelper.listFiles(FtpJBHelper.java:77)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFilesInDirectory(FTPClientWrapper.java:187)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFiles(FTPClientWrapper.java:148)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doGetChildren(FtpFileObject.java:141)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doListChildren(FtpFileObject.java:471)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:917)
    ... 29 more
2015-06-03 10:09:16,789 [2663223]   INFO - s.communicator.p2p.NetworkUtil - Call [http://192.168.4.115:2864/rpc2] AddOnlineUser.addOnlineUser([192.168.4.78, iuser, 2864, [daps-master], [AVAILABLE, 0]]) Connection timed out: connect 
2015-06-03 10:09:58,918 [2705352]   INFO - s.communicator.p2p.NetworkUtil - Call [http://192.168.4.30:2864/rpc2] AddOnlineUser.addOnlineUser([192.168.4.78, iuser, 2864, [daps-master], [AVAILABLE, 0]]) Connection timed out: connect 
2015-06-03 10:11:24,305 [2790739]   WARN - i.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode - Could not list the contents of folder "ftp://198.135.4.141/". 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not list the contents of folder "ftp://198.135.4.141/".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:926)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.getChildren(FtpFileObject.java:455)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChild(AbstractFileObject.java:1006)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool.createConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionManager.openConnection(RemoteConnectionManager.java:103)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeContext.getConnection(ServerTreeContext.java:88)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.computeFile(ServerTreeNode.java:269)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.ServerTreeNode.getChildren(ServerTreeNode.java:135)
    at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.SimpleTreeStructure.getChildElements(SimpleTreeStructure.java:25)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$32.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:1624)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1830)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.getChildrenFor(AbstractTreeUi.java:1621)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$4700(AbstractTreeUi.java:62)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$47.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:2708)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1830)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$2500(AbstractTreeUi.java:62)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$58$1.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:3386)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.ui.remotebrowser.WebServerTreeBuilder.runBackgroundLoading(WebServerTreeBuilder.java:90)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$58.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:3377)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.execute(AbstractTreeUi.java:1830)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi.access$2500(AbstractTreeUi.java:62)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeUi$59.run(AbstractTreeUi.java:3442)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:729)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:657)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3097)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3072)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2731)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2778)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpJBHelper.listFiles(FtpJBHelper.java:77)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFilesInDirectory(FTPClientWrapper.java:187)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.listFiles(FTPClientWrapper.java:148)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doGetChildren(FtpFileObject.java:141)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doListChildren(FtpFileObject.java:471)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:917)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Please include an FTP server log.

Comment: I tried enabling Always use LIST command , but that didn't help.

Comment: Can you include only a snippet of the log that corresponds to your test? The log you've posted spans 90 minutes! How do we know what part is relevant?

Answer (score 2):

I knew after spending hours that it would be a small thing that fixes it :)

Under `Advanced Options` select `Passive mode`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just changing the default FTP timeout setting. However, this can not be done by UI option. I archive it by modifying VM option.

1. using "Help -> Edit Custom VM Options" menu to create a custom vm option;
2. add a line "-Dcom.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.sftp.timeout=10000000";
3. reboot your IntelliJ.

ref: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-484?_ga=2.164114552.61182995.1577118457-651580832.1554239923